Implementing custom storage in angular-auth-oidc-client when using a standalone config in Angular
I'm using the provideAuth method in my main.ts file which allows to set the config. However the documentation of the library only shows how to implement custom storage using NgModules, which i'm not using since i'm using Angular standalone components.
I already implemented the AbstractSecurityStorage with a class that uses localStorage but I don't know how to tell the library to use this one instead of session storage.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Found the problem, it's because I was calling provideAuth() after I provided the custom storage in the boostrapApplication function. If I reverse the order it works as it overrides the default storage defined in provideAuth.
